# Cast int to enum

Tags: casting, enums, c++-cli

I'm trying to use a generic enum type in a C++/CLI helper class and I want it to default to 0 if the cast doesn't work.  My problem is that `result = (T)0;` doesn't work.  Is there a way around this?

> Error 1   error C2440: 'type cast' : cannot convert from 'int' to 'T'

```
generic <typename T> where T: value class, Enum
static void SetEnumPropertyValue(String^ value, [Out] T %result)
{
    if (String::IsNullOrEmpty(value))
            false;
    if (!Enum::TryParse<T>(value, true, result))
    {
        result = (T)0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Enum.TryParse should be Enum::TryParse btw.

Comment: @DeCaf Right.  I caught that after posting.  Thanks.

Comment: You can always edit your post to correct things like this. Might make it easier for people who want to copy your code and compile it to see what's wrong with it. (Just for future reference)

Comment: After some more research, the `if (!Enum::TryParse<T>(value, true, result))
    {
        result = (T)0;
    }` part isn't needed since tryparse defaults to the default of the enum.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the C++/CLI equivalent to C#'s default(T)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1962600/what-is-the-c-cli-equivalent-to-cs-defaultt), which Nish has answered correctly at http://voidnish.wordpress.com/2011/02/04/ccli-equivalent-for-cs-defaultt/

Comment: @BenVoigt The result is the same for this particular case, but the question is not the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either use:

```
   result = (T)Enum::ToObject(T::typeid, 0);
```

or the slightly "uglier":

```
   result = (T)(Object^)0;
```

Comment: Ah.  Object^ not Object.  Thanks a lot!